# Python - Using Spreadsheet Dictionary Once per sheet

Tags: python, excel

I'm not much of a Python dev and am in the process of creating a script which will pull all tables from a PDF into Excel. The idea is to then translate the keys of those tables to something meaningful so that I can import it into my DB. The tables are separated by sheets which is perfect.

So currently I have around 1k PDFs (all similar type) and I have a 'master' spreadsheet file which basically says 'If you see this keyword in the converted file, change the value which is in the dictionary'.

However, I want it so that once a key has been used in the dictionary, it cannot be used again in a different sheet.

I have been using Chat GPT to help me write this, but now it is getting confused as some of the keys in the converted Excel's repeat in multiple sheets.

For example:

**Sheet 1:**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 1 |
| Name | Bob |

*Should be:*

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1.ID | 1 |
| A1.Name | Bob |

**Sheet 2**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 4 |
| First Name | John |

*Should be:*

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A2.ID | 1 |
| A2.Name | Bob |

*But infact it is:*

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1.ID | 1 |
| A2.Name | Bob |

The code:

```py
def convert_to_dictionary(file_path):
    dictionary_file = pd.read_excel(dictionary_file_path, sheet_name="All")

    master_dictionary = {}
    num_columns = len(dictionary_file.columns)

    # Create a dictionary for each column starting from 2 and store them in the master dictionary
    for i in range(2, num_columns):
        current_column_dictionary = {
            str(row[i]).strip().lower(): str(row[1])
            for _, row in dictionary_file.iterrows()
        }
        master_dictionary[i] = current_column_dictionary

    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
    modified_sheets = []

    used_words_per_sheet = {}  # Dictionary to store used words for each sheet

    for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
        input_file = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=None)

        used_words = set()  # Set to store used words for the current sheet

        for column_number, column_dictionary in master_dictionary.items():
            input_file.iloc[:, 0] = input_file.iloc[:, 0].apply(
                lambda x, used_words=used_words, column_dictionary=column_dictionary: column_dictionary.get(
                    str(x).strip().lower(), x
                )
                if str(x).strip().lower() not in used_words
                else x
            )
            used_words.update(
                input_file.iloc[:, 0].apply(str).str.strip().str.lower()
            )  # Update used_words set

        used_words_per_sheet[
            sheet_name
        ] = used_words  # Store used words for the current sheet

        modified_sheets.append((sheet_name, input_file))

    # Save the modified sheets with sheet-specific names
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path) as writer:
        for sheet_name, modified_sheet in modified_sheets:
            modified_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

I did use ChatGPT for some of this...

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Its too long of a story for stackoverflow in my opinion. Lets simplify it, the immediate challenge at hand, is that you have an excel file with many sheets. Each sheet has one table of key value pairs, and you want to append A + sheet id + . to each key. Correct?

Comment: I do think it is quite long (as it's complicated) for what i'm trying to achieve, but what you said is partially correct - it's not appending, it is searching for a key in one sheet and comparing it to the dictionary. The key in the dictionary can only be used in the first sheet it is being used in (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

I cracked it

```
def convert_to_dictionary(file_path):
dictionary_file = pd.read_excel(dictionary_file_path, sheet_name="All")

# Create a defaultdict with a list as the default factory
dictionary = defaultdict(list)

# Populate the defaultdict with values from the DataFrame
for index, row in dictionary_file.iterrows():
    key = row["Code"]
    for column_name, value in row.items():
        if column_name != "Code" and pd.notna(value):
            dictionary[key].append(value.strip().lower())

xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
modified_sheets = []

for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    input_sheet = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=None)
    used_words = set()

    for column_number, column_name in enumerate(input_sheet.columns):
        for row_index, row in input_sheet.iterrows():
            keyword = str(row[column_number]).strip().lower()
            if (
                keyword in sum(dictionary.values(), [])
                and keyword not in used_words
            ):
                keyword = [
                    key for key, values in dictionary.items() if keyword in values
                ]
                row[0] = keyword[0]
                used_words.add(keyword[0])

    for word in used_words:
        dictionary.pop(word)

    modified_sheets.append((sheet_name, input_sheet))

# Save the modified sheets with sheet-specific names
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path) as writer:
    for sheet_name, modified_sheet in modified_sheets:
        modified_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```